# Wordpress custom post type link directly to edit page

Tags: wordpress, post, types

Let's say that I have a custom post type `books` with a single record (will be the only one). This post type will be displayed in admin menu. I want (when selecting this post type from the menu) to redirect me on edit page of this single record instead of edit page of all records (which is the default behavior).
Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a possible solution, though not the cleanest one is to use `$menu` global variable. 
Menu/submenu is internally stored in wordpress as an array:
Example for Post menu:

`[5]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Posts"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "edit_posts"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "edit.php"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(37) "menu-top menu-icon-post open-if-no-js"
    [5]=>
    string(10) "menu-posts"
    [6]=>
    string(20) "dashicons-admin-post"
  }`

The solution is to edit proper array index => value, as for above, to change the link from `edit.php` to `customlink.php` we need to do (in a proper function of course):

`global $menu;
$customLink = "customlink.php";
$menu[5][2] = $customLink;`

5 is the Post menu index (see above array)
2 is the link index: [2]=> string(8) "edit.php"

Is not the 'cleanest' solution for custom post types because menu index for CPTs can modify.
Hope this helps someone!